# How to bind gridview with some conditions in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
    DataTable dtbind = new DataTable();
        dtbind = objvehicleBAL.GetTaxdetails();

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; dtbind.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dtbind.Rows[i]["todate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            if (dt1 &lt; ((DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))))
            {
                GVTax.DataSource = dtbind.Rows[i];
                GVTax.DataBind();

            }

        }
```

I had written my conditions in if(). I want to bind only satisfied rows in grid. How can I write this?

Comment: I am getting this error "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource" with above code,how can i solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DataTable dtbind1 = objvehicleBAL.GetTaxdetails();
 DataTable dtbind2 = new DataTable();

 foreach (DataRow row in dtbind1.Rows)
 {
     DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(row["todate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
     if (dt1 < ((DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))))
          dtbind2.Rows.Add(row);
     }
 }

 GVTax.DataSource = dtbind2;
 GVTax.DataBind();
```

Comment: although this solution may be worked! but i would prefer using either DataView rowfilter or filtering the record on the server by adding where clause in sql query(this prevents looping each row and perform operations on it). and i think u must dispose or set to null the dtbind1 as its no longer used later becoz u got the results in dtbind2 right..

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to bind the `Grid` in loop on the Row of data table rather filter the `DataTable` by the *condition* you want and bind it once. You can get `DataView` from the data table and use its property [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) to apply the date filter.

```
dtbind = objvehicleBAL.GetTaxdetails();  //Filter the record in GetTaxdetails 
DataView dv = dtbind.DefaultView; //or use DataView with RowFilter
dv .RowFilter = "todate = #"  + DateTime.Now.AddDays(15).ToString() + "#";
GVTax.DataSource = dv;
GVTax.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to bind each `row` and call `DataBind` mehtod each time.
Just use the following:

```
protected void BindGrid()
{
        DataTable dtbind = new DataTable();
        dtbind=objvehicleBAL.GetTaxdetails();//get the rows filtered in SQL
        if(dtbind!=null && dtbind.Rows.Count>0)//always check for null for preventing exception
        {
          GVTax.DataSource = dtbind;
        }
        GVTax.DataBind();   
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I think the OP requires to check the condition on each data table row and bind it to the gridview.

Comment: do u think instead adding a filter in sql query would hit performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Select` method of `DataTable` along with a filtering expression, to get the rows which match your criteria. Then, bind it to to your `GridView`.

```
string filterExp = "todate < dateadd(day,15,getdate())";
var filtered = dtBind.Select(filterExp);
GVTax.DataSource = filtered ;
GVTax.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another datatable and fill the rows satisfying your condition in the second datatable and bind your gridview with second datatable (having filtered rows)

```
dttableNew  = dttableOld.Clone();  

            foreach (DataRow drtableOld in dttableOld.Rows)
            {
               if (/*put some Condition */)
               {
                  dtTableNew.ImportRow(drtableOld);
               }
            }

            GVTax.DataSource = dtTableNew;

           GVTax.DataBind();
```